# PHP Mysql IN clause does not work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my code:

```
public function fetchAllPhotoRatings($table_name,$arrayOfPics)
{
    $mysqli = $this->returnDatabaseConnection();
    $picsArrayToString = "";


    foreach ($arrayOfPics as $value) 
    {
        $picsArrayToString .= '"'.$value.'",';
    }
    $picsArrayToString = rtrim($picsArrayToString, ",");

    // Running the below in PHPMyAdmin works
    //echo "SELECT number_of_ratings,voted_on_image,rated_by from $table_name where voted_on_Image in($picsArrayToString)";exit;


    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare ( "SELECT number_of_ratings, voted_on_image, rated_by from $table_name where voted_on_Image in(?)" ))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param ( "s", $picsArrayToString);


        $stmt->execute ();
        $stmt->bind_result ($number_of_ratings,$voted_on_image,$rated_by);

        echo $rated_by; // Not binding, this value is false.
        $array = array();
        $i = 0;
        while ($stmt->fetch())
        { echo "here";exit; // Trying to see if it enters the while() loop
            if (isset ($voted_on_image))
            {
                $array[$i]['number_of_ratings']         = $number_of_ratings;
                $array[$i]['voted_on_image']            = $voted_on_image;
                $array[$i]['rated_by']                  = $rated_by;
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $stmt->close ();
    }
    $mysqli->close ();


    if (empty($array)) // This shouldnt fire, but it does :(
    {
        die("Invalid data");
    }
    else
    {
        return $array;
    }

}
```

If I run the SQL directly in PHPMyAdmin it runs fine, but when I run this script it does not enter into the while() loop / does not fetch anything from the DB.
I think it has something to do with the IN clause of mySql... or?

Generated SQL from above:

> SELECT number_of_ratings,voted_on_image,rated_by from
>   Gallery_ratings where voted_on_Image
>   in("cd4ab876c9ce3e854d95e53b07e97ecb.jpg","a1b37032887c916ded69f1f023845ef6.jpg")

Comment: I think your query looks like `IN('blah,mah,tah')` so it searches for a string

Comment: instead of looping an array you can use implode function.

Comment: Provide us the content of `$picsArrayToString`variable

Comment: @Mihai, Nope, my IN looks like this IN("blah","mah","tah").
Thanks, I know I can use implode as well :)

Comment: Please post the generate query after passing all values.

Comment: @ApulGupta and Joel Salamin, posted above

Answer (score 2):

MySQLI does not have an array (or enum..) type, there are only `i` integer, `s` string, `b` binary/blob, `d` for double.

Your query should be prepared like:

```
$array       = array('one', 'two', 'three');

$query       = "SELECT .... IN ("
             . implode(', ', array_fill(0, sizeof($array), '?'))
             . ")";

$stmt->bind_param(str_repeat('s', sizeof($array)), $array);
```

Output is like:

```
SELECT .... IN (?, ?, ?)
```

bind_param then looks like:

```
->bind_param('sss', $array);
```

**If I was wrong with this assumption...** because you said the output actually looks correct, I have some more ideas:

```
try {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT number_of_ratings, voted_on_image, rated_by from $table_name where voted_on_Image in(?)");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Error exception
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

if ($stmt !== false) {
    // go on..

    while (true) {
        try {
            $fetchStatus = $stmt->fetch();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Error exception
            echo $e->getMessage();
            break;
        }

        if ($fetchStatus === false) {
            echo $mysqli->error;
            break;
        }
        elseif ($fetchStatus === null) {
            // no more results
            break;
        }
        else {
            // all fine
        }

        // ...
    }

} else {
    echo $mysqli->error;
}
```

Comment: Thats a bit confusing, can you write it with my code please?

Comment: I almost used your code.

Comment: because using your code gives me 'Warning: str_repeat() expects exactly 2 parameters, 3 given in '

Comment: @Ryan I guess you didn't check for errors, try the code I added.

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in ` the line in question is: `$stmt->bind_param(str_repeat('s', sizeof($arrayOfPics)), $arrayOfPics);`

Comment: @Ryan I already said it, do some of the work on your own, lazy guy!

Comment: Dude, I am trying your code as well as the other guys code in seperate files, I have slept 4hrs in from yesterday... gimme a break please

Comment: Where I initialized $array, try: `$array = array_filter($arrayOfPics);`

Comment: I think I screwed up somewhere, can you look here and tell me if this is right: http://pastebin.com/CCFQp5bj (it's 7 in the evening and I'm going to have my first meal of today :(  :

Answer (score 0):

parameterized queries don't play will with `IN` clauses because the `?` gets replaced with `'boundValue'` note the quotes!

what you can do is something like:

```
$numberOfPics=count($arrayOfPics);
$placeHolders = implode(',',array_fill(0,  $numberOfPics , '?'));
$query = "SELECT number_of_ratings, voted_on_image, rated_by from $table_name 
     where voted_on_Image in($placeHolders)"

$params=implode('',array_fill(0,$numberOfPics,'s'));


$stmt->bind_param($params, $arrayOfPics);
```

Comment: @downvoter thanks for the feedback. I wander if you could provide some more constructive info in a comment?

Comment: @DanFromGermany I will admit, I did steal the last line, as I saw you posted a similar answer while i was typing out mine. too bad I stole the only line that didn't actually work

Comment: I am getting two errors: `Notice: Undefined variable: array in ...` and `Warning: str_repeat() expects exactly 2 parameters, 3 given in...`

Comment: @Ryan C'mon you can do some of the work on your own, can't you? I mean, lookup the [function reference](http://php.net/str_repeat), notice there is a bracket in the wrong place, fix it on your own , ....

Comment: I get this: `Warning: array_fill() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in...` for this line: `$params=implode('',array_fill(0,'s',$numberOfPics));`

Comment: sorry got the parameters reversed see edit

Comment: Is this correct: `$stmt->bind_param($params, $arrayOfPics);` because then we are giving it an array when it expects something like `$one,$two,$three` etc

Comment: Because I am getting this error: `Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in ...` for the above `$stmt->bind_param($params, $arrayOfPics);`